# Jade Interpolation #{ } vs Buffered =' '

Tags: node.js, pug

When injecting data from a controller

```
module.exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'HelloWorld' } );
};
```

into a Jade template, I can either do buffered

```
h1= title
```

or interpolation

```
#{ title }
```

Both appear to do the same thing, but have two different names and syntax. I know this may turn out to be trivial, but I have not been able to find out the difference between the two. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Using `#{title}` is used to concatenate information as well

```
h1 This is my title #{title}, well is look cool!!
```

And the use of `=title`, to insert the contents of the variable without concatenating

```
h1= title
```

The first is much easier to concatenate strings.